Gauss Hypergeometric Function Simplification
Recently I've been developing a strategy to handle a large class of Feynman integrals that uses some series expansions to simplify the angular integrals. This always leads to multiple sums over hypergeometric functions of the form ${}_nF_{n-1}$.
In the case I'm currently considering, after much simplification I am led to the following double sum:
$$
\sum_{l,m\geq0}f_{l,m}\left\{\frac{A+l}{l-m}{}_2F_1(1,-l;A+m+1;z)+\frac{A+m}{m-l}{}_2F_1(1,-m;A+l+1;z)\right\},
$$
where $A$ and $z$ are real numbers, and $f_{l,m}$ is some (unimportant) real-valued function of the kinematic parameters. I'm stumped by the quantity in brackets. Of course, the bracketed function looks at first glance to be singular at $l=m$, but it is quite easily expressible in terms of digamma functions at this point, since $l=m$ implies parametric derivatives of the Gauss hypergeometric functions. This doesn't really make the sum itself any easier to solve, but at least convergence is not a problem.
Is there any way to simplify the bracketed quantity? The difference in the denominator really seems to complicate things, but the specific values of the numerator parameters in the hypergeometric functions seem very conducive to further simplification ($a_1=1$ cancels the factorial in the series definition of ${}_2F_1$, and $a_2=-m,-l$ truncates the otherwise infinite-degree polynomial at a finite order). I've been combing to no avail through all the standard tables of hypergeometric identities, searching for an identity that fits this case.
I also tried replacing the hypergeometric functions with the integral representation of the incomplete beta function (a specific case of ${}_2F_1$ with $a_1=1$ and $a_2=-n$ for positive, integral $n$), which gives me something proportional to
$$
\frac{x^l-x^m}{l-m}.
$$
Noting the derivatives induced at $l=m$, I thought I could then use discrete calculus, particularly the discrete analogue of the fundamental theorem of calculus and summation by parts, but this, too, led me precisely nowhere.
It would seem that I'm out of luck and will have to rethink my strategy. Is this the case? For the record, I'm aware of Gosper's and Zeilberger's algorithms and WZ pairs, but I don't have access to any computer implementations of these schemes, so naturally I haven't been very far down this avenue.
Thank you in advance for the help and advice.
Update:
While I'm hoping for a simplification of the original problem, I'd happily settle for different representations of
$$
\frac{x^l-x^m}{l-m}.
$$
Note, however, that I've tried using the integral representation
$$
\frac{x^l-x^m}{l-m}=x^m\ \frac{x^{l-m}-1}{l-m}=x^m\int_1^x dx'\ x'^{l-m-1},
$$
which leads me to an Appell function and overall makes the solution even less tractable. What I'm really looking for is a way to hide or factor the denominator, $l-m$, so I can more easily sum over $l$ and $m$.
If it helps, the origin of the $l-m$ is the simplification
$$
{}_3F_2(a,b,c;a+1,b+1;z)=\frac{a}{a-b}{}_2F_1(b,c;b+1;z)+\frac{b}{b-a}{}_2F_1(a,c;a+1;z),
$$
where $a=A+l-1$, $b=A+m-1$, and $c=A+l+m$; the bracketed expression then follows from an Euler transformation. If there's another expression for this case of ${}_3F_2$ that circumvents the appearance of $l-m$, then all the better.
